# C# How to Insert a Zero date?

Tags: c#, database, exception, date

I need to convert a zero string say "00000000" into date and insert in DB but I cannot use

```
Date.ParseExact("00000000","yyyymmdd",null);
```

Also tried with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Getting the following Exception:

> The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

Comment: There is no 00-00-0000 date. The Min date is 01-01-0001.

Comment: What happened to the 0th of Zeroary, 0000? I think they change the calendar too often. [More serious:] Internally a `DateTime` counts ticks from 1st of January, 0001, and to get the `DateTime` where the _ticks_ count is zero, one can use `default(DateTime)` which is equivalent to `new DateTime()`. There happens to exist also a `static` field with this value, `DateTime.MinValue`. The representation in your database might be quite different, depending on what database you use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, because there is a min value of DateTime and thats certainly not 0. You could use a nullable DateTime and make your field nullable in the database as well.

To see the minimum value you can try this for academic purposes:

```
// Define an uninitialized date.

DateTime date1 = new DateTime();
Console.Write(date1);
if (date1.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.MinValue.ToString() + "  (Equals Date.MinValue)");
// The example displays the following output:
//    1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM  (Equals Date.MinValue)
```

More info on nullable types:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Always someone thats faster :(

Comment: Thanks for this info. Saved my time trying other means of inserting it. Can you also show how to create a nullable datetime. I mean if I make "00000000" null is there a way a datetime value of null ?

Comment: Of course you should take a look at Nullable<T> or declare it using syntactic sugar like these examples: int?, DateTime?, bool? .

Comment: While I do agree that the nullable DateTime type `DateTime?` is the appropriate choice here, it's worth pointing out that there is a property called DateTime.Ticks that will be zero for a default-constructed DateTime. It's the earliest time that can be represented in a DateTime, i.e. 01/01/0001 @ 00:00:00. If you *know* that is never going to be a valid time, you could in theory use that as a flag. But that's use-by-convention, and it's far less obvious than using a nullable DateTime.

Comment: DateTime? is just syntactic sugar for Nullable<DateTime>, it compiles into the same MSIL, what people choose is just a matter of choice.